# how to iterate through n amounts of lists in parallel?

Tags: python

There are already many answers to 'how to iterate through 2 lists in parallel'. However, I am trying to figure out how to iterate through an arbitrary amount of lists.

For example, the following requires me to know beforehand how many lists i have

```
for f, b in zip(foo, bar):
    print(f, b)
```

But I am using `os.listdir()` to get an N amount of subfolders, and then I want to iterate through all those subfolder in parallel.

```
for (every nth element) in (each subfolder found):
    do something
```

Currently I have always done this manually but I'd really like to know how to do this more elegantly, i.e. without any knowledge of how many lists to iterate through.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use `zip`, since it accepts more than two arguments. Given a list of lists, where you want to iterate through their `i'th` arguments in a loop:

```
lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
for parallel in zip(*lists):
    print(parallel)
```

prints:

```
(1, 1, 1)
(2, 2, 2)
(3, 3, 3)
(4, 4, 4)
(5, 5, 5)
```

Or, with a variant of your problem description:

```
import os

subdirs = [os.listdir(f) for f in os.listdir(my_dir) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(my_dir, f))]
for parallel in zip(*subdirs):
    # work on them in parallel
```

It should be noted that `zip` cuts off on the end of the shortest list it gets. If you want to pad every list with `None`s instead, you should use `itertools.zip_longest`, like so:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
# get subdirs same as before
for parallel in zip_longest(*subdirs):
    print([f for f in parallel if f is not None])  # don't show padded entries
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just unpack the list of lists:

```
list_of_lists = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [5,6,7]]

for x in zip(*list_of_lists):
    for y in x:
        print(y)
1
2
4
2
3
5
3
4
6
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know how many lists you'll have in advance:

```
for subdirs in zip(*(os.listdir(p) for p in root_dirs)):

for paths in zip(*(os.listdir(p) for p in root_dirs))::
    do_something(paths)  # paths is a tuple like (paths[0], paths[1], ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

for your list of subfolders:

```
subfolders = os.listdir(some_path)
```

you can create a second for loop around your first one:

```
# iterate through subfolders of some_path
for subfolder in subfolders:
    #iterate through elements in subfolder
    for element in os.listdir(os.path.join(some_path, subfolder):
        # you take it from here
```

You might also want to take a look at `os.walk` to recursively iterate through a directory tree